# Shared Image is not visible in chat room

Tags: java, android, firebase

I created the chat application where I'm trying to share the media, Its not appearing the chat room. But its getting saved in the firebase with the url in the database.

Can anyone help me to figure out this.

```
 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

    Calendar cdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    final String savedate = currentdate.format(cdate.getTime());

    Calendar ctime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currenttime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    final String savetime = currenttime.format(ctime.getTime());

    String timeStamp = savedate + " " + savetime;

    messages.setMessage(downloadUri.toString());
    messages.setSenderID(sender_uid);
    messages.setReceiverID(receiver_uid);
    messages.setType("image");
    messages.setTimeStamp(timeStamp);

    String id = rootRef1.push().getKey();
    rootRef1.child(id).setValue(messages);

    String id1 = rootRef2.push().getKey();
    rootRef2.child(id1).setValue(messages);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Image is picked from the gallery. After clicking on the send button its getting uploaded in the firebase but that image is not going to user chat room and not getting displayed.

Comment: Are you using the correct URL?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes it's the same.